# relation"table name" does not exist error on heroku run for postgresql table load

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models, relation, heroku-postgres

```
*After deploying my django model in heroku and migrations,
```

### I am unable to load data into the postgres table by batch run 
*

Ex:

```
heroku run python ProddbUpload.py
```

I am disappointed with below error

Running python ProddbUpload.py

```
on ⬢ spellbeeword... up, run.9508 (Free)
relation "spellbeeword_tb" does not exist
```

Verified table name Spellbeeword_tb exist in my Postgres database in heroku environment using pg:psql
My code to upload data into above mentioned table

```
import os
import psycopg2
def writedb(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        with  open("spellbee/docs/Spell_Bee_Word_db.csv", 'r') as f:
            cur.copy_from(f,'Spellbeeword_tb',sep=',')
            # commit changes
            conn.commit()
    
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
            f.close()
def main():
    DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
        writedb(conn)
    except(Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

In pg:psql  query, it shows
database connection for my table as  --> Connecting to **postgresql-flat-40316**
But in heroku environment variables , it is showing as
=== spellbeeword Config Vars

DATABASE_URL: postgres://mlsudzmqspljyc:c2e68f055e685aa45dde87@ec2-18-206-20-102.compute-1.amazonaws.com:
By default the above config made.

I dont know how to connect postgresql-flat-40316/Spellbeeword_tb

when I checked with the below code, nothing printed

cur.execute('SELECT version()')

## display the PostgreSQL database server version

db_version = cur.fetchone()
print(db_version)

```
 Pls help me to import my data into table created by django model in heroku.
```

I think , in  heroku run it is not identifying the correct database to connect . 
I followed heroku postgresl django deployment documentation where 
DATABASE_URL were configured by dj-database-url installation 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python  
I ran the above dbupload code via **heroku run python <dbupload-filename.py>** 
requirements and settings.py were pushed to heroku before this run seperately
# setting DATABASE url
DATABASES = {'default' : dj_database_url.config() }

See my current pg status

```
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           0/20
PG Version:            13.2
Created:               2021-04-06 10:54 UTC
Data Size:             9.0 MB
Tables:                13
Rows:                  68/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-flat-40316
```

`table row: ('d7uobuibp87kvk', 'public', 'Spellbeeword_tb', 'BASE TABLE', None, None, None, None, None, 'YES', 'NO', None)`

inside database ,my target table exist but it shows

```
relation "spellbeeword_tb" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM Spellbeeword_tb;
                      ^
```

Can anyone suggest how to speccify table name in  the code to recognize

Answer (score 0):

Now I identified it is case sensitive for mixed case in table name. Hence I gave table name in " double quotes, then it can recognize the table

```
 `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM "Spellbeeword_tb";')`
```

and no error thrown for the above sql statement and fetch the table....
But relation does not exist still persist because of below code

```
cur.copy_from(f,"Spellbeeword_tb",sep=',')
```

relation "spellbeeword_tb" does not exist

Answer (score -1):

Finally identified Postgres database is case sensitive. As defined table in Camel Case, it cannot able to identify table name relationship (eventhough table is given in quotes(both " /')
Hence I modified table name to lower case . Now it can able to identify the table.